# React and .NET app data fetching in portions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reactjs, redux-saga

I tried to find the answer to my question, but it seems like I am either missing correct terminology or it really is a bit tricky to do.

I am trying to see if it is possible to utilise either Lazy Loading, or data sent from API in portions periodically, so loading time does not take as long to reach first render. My current system where an array of over 1000 objects is being fetched from .NET API into React UI just does not work as I would like it to.

I would like to skip pagination if possible.

Comment: Yes it's very much possible to implement paging in an API. Your question is very broad and is unlikely to get you the answer you are looking for. Please be more specific.

Comment: I am not looking to create paginated solution, quite a contrary. Either lazy loading or some form of multiple responses from the API rather than one huge chunk.

Comment: This is exactly the definition of paging...

Comment: From my understanding pagination was always involving pages with n amount of results per page, rather than what I am looking for. @ChrisPickford .

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the endpoint `GET /data?show=X&skip=Y`,
for first request get data from `/data?show=10`,
then whenever you want (for example when user reaches the bottom of website), do `/data?show=10&skip=10`

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I hope it helps somehow :)

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the solution I am looking for! Thank you so much. As soon as I will test this I will get back with an answer if it works as expected.